# Formatting HH:MM column when reading data into SAS

Tags: time, sas, informat

I am an `R` user and `SAS` beginner trying to read a csv file into `SAS`. The problem I am facing is with a column called "TIME" which contains time data in the format "hh:mm " for e.g. "12:23 PM". In `R` it is as simple as `as.POSIXct(df$TIME, format = "%I:%M %p")` and my hour is converted to time values instantly (with time-zone and today's date which can be removed).

This is how I tried to implement this in SAS:

```
/* firstly `rename` "TIME" to "DAY_HOUR" */
data mid.prac1;
set mid.prac1;
rename time = DAY_HOUR;
run;
/*runs successfully */

/* remove unwanted characters from DAY_HOUR */
data mid.prac2;
set mid.prac1;
DAY_HOUR = compress(DAY_HOUR, 'PMAM');
proc print; run;
/* runs successfully */

/* format hh:mm as time */
data mid.prac3;
set mid.prac2;  
informat DAY_HOUR time10.;
run;
**/*Error: ERROR 48-59: The informat $TIME was not found or could not be loaded.*/**
```

The `time` `informat` does not exist? I read this documentation on the SAS website: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000201204.htm and I think I am doing it right. I am new to the whole SAS universe so apologies if I am not following conventions in asking questions and pasting sample data etc.

Comment: Look at these mate. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_intervals_sect011.htm#etsug.intervals.itvformats2

Comment: looked and tried : `informat DAY_HOUR HHMM10.;` . same error. "ERROR 48-59: The format $HHMM was not found or could not be loaded."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just parse it through the input function:

```
DAY_HOUR_FOR_ME = INPUT(DAY_HOUR,TIME10.);
```

This should convert the DAY_HOUR character variable to a DAY_HOUR_FOR_ME numeric variable. If you need to format this as a time, use the `FORMAT` statement:

```
FORMAT DAY_HOUR_FOR_ME time10.;
```

OK...

```
FORMAT DAY_HOUR_FOR_ME timeampm11.;
```

**Informats**

Informats are used by SAS to read data. So, given a string looking like this:

```
09:00:00
```

You can ask SAS to convert this to a numeric representation of 9AM, by submitting:

```
time_i_want = input(text,time8.);
```

Where 8 is simply the length of the string `text`. SAS will then store a variable `time_i_want` as the number of seconds between 00:00 and 09:00.

**Formats**

Formats are used to display data in a usable format. If I asked you the time and you told me how many seconds there had been since the 1st January 1960, I'd be displeased. However, this is how SAS stores DATETIME values:

```
'01JAN1960:00:01:00'dt = 60;
'31DEC1959:23:59:30'dt = -30;
```

etc.

So, the `FORMAT` statement can be used in any datastep to force the resulting dataset (that which is named in the `DATA` statement) to display values in a particular format.

`TIMEAMPM`

is one such format. However, TIMEAMPM is not an **INFORMAT**

**Informats and formats**

Some informats are mirrored by equivalent formats. `TIME8.` is an example. You can ask SAS to read in a time value using an **informat**:

01:00:32

This is then stored as a numeric value `3632`. It can then be formatted using the `TIME8.` **format**, which displays it as such:

01:00:32

Comment: Thanks ! Follow up : Can I keep the AM / PM indicator somehow or convert it to a 24 hour clock otherwise I am losing that information . . .

Comment: Yep, the value is kept as a time value containing the number of seconds since midnight (00:00), so you can find the right format to display AM/PM if needed. Google 'SAS Time formats by category' to save me some typing.

Comment: Cheers for the accept/upvote though, much appreciated.

Comment: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000201272.htm , found the page and tried but not working ! `data mid.prac4;
 set mid.prac1;
 DAY_HOUR_FOR_ME = input(DAY_HOUR, timeampm10.);
 format DAY_HOUR_FOR_ME timeampm11.;
 run;`  ERROR 48-59: The informat TIMEAMPM was not found or could not be loaded.

Comment: `TIMEAMPMP` is not an INFORMAT. Informats are used to read data, so SAS doesn't like it when you try to use them in `FORMAT` statements. Keep `INPUT(DAY_HOUR,TIME10.)` as such, don't use `TIMEAMPM` in that statment at all.

Comment: Should I try: `data mid.prac4; set mid.prac1; DAY_HOUR_FOR_ME = input(DAY_HOUR, time10.); format DAY_HOUR_FOR_ME timeampm10.; run;` ?

Comment: That seems to have worked . . it does not appear like the second of the day but AM / PM . . now to try running some difference calculations and check if it is working correctly . . Thanks ! Surprising this hasn't come up on SO before . .

Comment: Happy to accept edits to this post, but I think I've covered informats and formats. There must be another SO post that covers it as @vagabond says.

Comment: Thanks @mjsqu . That's extensive! Upvote the Q if you think it's worthwhile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66370/discussion-between-mjsqu-and-vagabond).